# how to add index.php in the URL through htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Actually I need to add index.php in my application URL through htaccess file.

My URL is like this.

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/xyz/abs.html
```

I need to change this into.

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/index.php/xyz/abs.html
```

Can anyone tell me what i need to be write in htaccess file.

Any Help will be appreciating.

Thanks.

Comment: are you using any framework ?, what is your current `.htaccess` ?

Answer (score 5):

Have this rule in `/myapp/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myapp/

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably an *internal rewrite* is required, not an external redirect? In which case, try something like the following, using mod_rewrite in your root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php/
RewriteRule ^myapp/(.*) /myapp/index.php/$1 [L]
```

The `RewriteCond` directive is required to prevent a rewrite loop. (Only rewrite if it doesn't already contain "/index.php/".)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /myapp/xyz/([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /myapp/index.php/xyz/%1.html [R,L,NC]
```