# How to get rid of index.php in url with Wordpress Rest API

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have correctly setup my site locally and everything works. However, when I deployed that to a blank EC2 instance, I see that wp-json (Rest API) does not work. It works only when I put an index.php in between. In other words

This works locally:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json
```

But I need to have this on the EC2 server to make it work.

```
http://A.B.C.D/wordpress/index.php/wp-json
```

On the server, I have installed apache2 and I have not messed up with the configs yet. I am familiar with wordpress but I not so much familiar with config tweaks on apache. I have also gone thru thousands of previously posted questions, but none of them seem to answer my problem.

Comment: I think you can use .htaccess to accomplish this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31239342/how-to-add-index-php-in-the-url-through-htaccess

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to have by `a2enmod rewrite` in your terminal.

Then in your Apache Configuration file, make sure you have the following:

```
<Directory #Wordpress directory here#>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All #allows .htaccess directives in the next step
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then make sure you have the following content in your root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Please consider making my answer as accepted if you found it to be useful